# Управление Hyper-V (старт/стоп) c помощью Ansible

Tags: windows-10, ansible, hyper-v, alpine-linux

На Windows 10 стоит Hyper-V, в которой создана тестовая vm с Alpine Linux.
Подскажите, как ей управлять (включать/выключать) с помощью Ansible?

Comment: А вы пытались управлять как-нибудь уже?

Comment: Насколько я понял модуля для управления Hyper-V нет, но можно запускать powershell-скрипты Strat-VM -Name <namevm>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- name: Start Hyper-V VM
        win_shell: Start-VM -Name <namevm>
```